# How to call the ClassifierBasedTagger() in NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, named-entity-recognition

I have followed in the documentation from nltk book (chapter 6 and 7) and other ideas to train my own model for named entity recognition. After building a  feature function and ClassifierBasedTagger like this:

```
class NamedEntityChunker(ChunkParserI):
    def __init__(self, train_sents, feature_detector=features, **kwargs):
        assert isinstance(train_sents, Iterable)
        tagged_sents = [[((w,t),c) for (w,t,c) in
                         tree2conlltags(sent)]
                        for sent in train_sents]

        #other possible option: self.feature_detector = features
        self.tagger = ClassifierBasedTagger(tagged_sents, feature_detector=feature_detector, **kwargs)

    def parse(self, tagged_sent):
        chunks = self.tagger.tag(tagged_sent)

        iob_triplets = [(w, t, c) for ((w, t), c) in chunks]

        # Transform the list of triplets to nltk.Tree format
        return conlltags2tree(iob_triplets)
```

I am having problems when caling the classifiertagger from another script where I load my traning and test data. I call the classifier using a portion from my training data for testing purpose from:

```
chunker = NamedEntityChunker(training_samples[:500])
```

No matter what I change in my classifier I keept getting the error:

```
   self.tagger = ClassifierBasedTagger(tagged_sents, feature_detector=feature_detector, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'feature_detector'
```

What am I doing wrong here, I supossed the feature function is working fine and I don't have to pass anything else when calling NamedEntityChunker().

my second question, is there a way to save the model being trained and reuse it lataer, how can I approach this?
This is a follow up of my [last question on training data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43489724/train-corpus-for-ner-with-nltk-ieer-or-conll2000-corpus)

Thanks for any advise

Comment: You should ask only one question in each posting. But the answer to your second question is yes: Use the `pickle` library. It's in the nltk book too, google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally realised what I was missing:
when defining BasedTagger you have to pass an argument for "tagged_sents", like this:

```
#self.tagger = ClassifierBasedTagger(train=train_sents, feature_detector=features, **kwargs)
```

now when I call the chunker NamedEntityChunker() everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your code is exactly as you report it? This should not produce the problem you report; but you *will* get this behavior if you pass a keyword argument that is also a key in the `kwargs` variable:

```
>>> def test(a, b):   # In fact the signature of `test` is irrelevant
        pass
>>> args = { 'a'=1, 'b'=2 }
>>> test(a=0, **args)
TypeError: test() got multiple values for keyword argument 'a'
```

So, figure out where the problem arises and fix it. Have your methods print out their arguments to help you debug the problem.